# How to upload .bat file in Azure Batch and run that Batch file

Tags: azure, batch-file, azure-batch

I want to upload a .bat file in Azure and run that .bat file i try to using batch azure to make an pool and run job's task but i dnt understand what to to for run.

my demo file is NewFile.bat that store in Azure Storage a/c In NewFile.bat

```
copy /b NUL EmptyFile.txt
```

for making new text file in storage a/c.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Tip:` You might \ probably want to add more detail to your question so that its clear how far you understand azure batch concepts.

Regarding your question:

- How to upload a resource?
- Here is a small tutorial which can tell you how you can upload the resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-parallel-dotnet
- also there are few concetps like `resourceFiles` or `application package` et. al. which you should familiar with but the tutorial link will help you here.

Tutorial will cover:

> You learn how to:
>
> - Add an application package to your Batch account
> - Authenticate with Batch and Storage accounts
> - Upload input files to Storage
> - Create a pool of compute nodes to run an application
> - Create a job and tasks to process input files
> - Monitor task execution
> - Retrieve output files

Hope this helps as guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Create your pool and job in Azure Batch Service. Create an Application Package containing your `.bat` file. Create the task with that Application Package. In the command line, add:

```
cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_<package name>#<version>%<path_to_your_batch_file>
```